# android json parsing error - JSONArray cannot be converted JSONObject

Tags: android, xml, json, parsing

i am converting a xml content into JSON content and the content is as follows

```
{
    "response":
    {
        "seatlist":
        {
            "seat":
            {
                "balance":85694.6,"num":12
            },
            "seat":
            {
                "balance":85694.6,"num":12
            }
        },
        "userid":"8970ca285d9c4e4d",
        "seatnum":12,
        "session":"online"
    }
}
```

I am able to get the userid and seatnum in the following way

```
JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");
            out.setUserid(response.getString("userid"));
            out.setBalance(Double.valueOf(response.getString("balance")));
```

Now the problem is i need to parse the following content and need to get "num" value

```
"seatlist":
        {
            "seat":
            {
                "balance":85694.6,"num":12
            },
            "seat":
            {
                "balance":85694.6,"num":12
            }
        }
```

here is my code i am using

JSONObject objList = response.getJSONObject("seatlist");
        String n = String.valueOf(objList.getJSONObject("seat"));
        if(objList.getJSONObject("seat").get("userId").equals(userId))
        {
            String num = String.valueOf(objList.getJSONObject("seat").get("num"));
            out.setSeatNum(Integer.valueOf(num));
        }

if i have one seat value i am able to get "num" value else i am getting JSON exception

Pls give me a suggestion in this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
"response":
{
    "seatlist":
    {
        "seat":
        {
            "balance":85694.6,"num":12
        },
        "seat":
        {
            "balance":85694.6,"num":12
        }
    },
    "userid":"8970ca285d9c4e4d",
    "seatnum":12,
    "session":"online"
}
}
```

means an object with an object called response. this contains an object called seatlist. this contains 2 objects called seat (but this is wrong! this should be an array!). and so on..

to read this you can use

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(yourresponse);
JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");

JSONObject seatlist = response.getJSONObject("seatlist");
JSONObject userid = response.getJSONObject("userid");
JSONObject seatnum = response.getJSONObject("seatnum");
JSONObject session = response.getJSONObject("session");
```

now seatlist contains.

```
   {
    "seat":
    {
        "balance":85694.6,"num":12
    },
    "seat":
    {
        "balance":85694.6,"num":12
    }
}
```

which is wrong, since it contains 2 elements with same name. Now you can either call it by index like this:

```
 JSONObject seat1 = seatlist.getJSONObject(1);
 JSONObject seat2 = seatlist.getJSONObject(2);


 seat1.getString("balanace"); seat1.getInt("num");
```

or you can iterate through the JSONObject.

At least it should be an Array instead of JSONOBject.

This means it should look like this.

```
{
"response": {
"seatlist": [
    "seat":
    {
        "balance":85694.6,"num":12
    },
    "seat":
    {
        "balance":85694.6,"num":12
    }
],
"userid":"8970ca285d9c4e4d",
"seatnum":12,
"session":"online"
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to get a JSONArray in an JSONObject. That is not possible.
Get the Array and then iterate through the array to get the objects:

```
JSONObject objList = response.getJSONArray("seatlist");
for(int i = 0, i<objList.lenght(); i++){
   JSONObject json = objList.get(i);
}
```